# Why does the globals()['__builtins__'] type change when being imported? Does Python create a new __builtins__ object for each module?

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

Let's say we have some module **A** with the following code:

```
# A

foo = globals()['__builtins__']

print(foo)
print(type(foo))
```

Running it gives the output:

```
<module 'builtins' (built-in)>
<class 'module'>
```

However, if we import module **A** into another module **B**:

```
# B

import A
```

The following is printed:

```
{'__name__': 'A', '__doc__': None, '__package__': '', '__loader__': <_frozen_importlib ...
<class 'dict'>
```

So our 'builtins' module turns into a dictionary, while all the other elements of globals() stay the same. Would be interesting to understand the machinery behind this.